# intermittent SQL query takes time in ignite

Tags: ignite

**Tool**: Apache Ignite v2.6
**Client** : Ignite JDBC Thin Driver

**Case**: Have a cache with several entries and can be accessed over SQL query. When tried a simple query, the result set is obtained in 18 ms. But the same query if executed multiple times.. the 4th or 7th time the Query Execution time shoots to 1.5 to 2 seconds even. Could anyone suggest any optimization

Edit: Adding the cache configuration. Though the cache mode in mentioned to be REPLICATED, we raised only one node. we just try to run simple select queries, like select * from CACHENAME; and it return in quick (20 ms). But if we repeat the query multiple times ..may be the 4th or so hit will take a few seconds.

```
    <property name="clientConnectorConfiguration">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.ClientConnectorConfiguration">
            <property name="maxOpenCursorsPerConnection" value="512" />
            <property name="socketSendBufferSize" value="65536"/>
            <property name="socketReceiveBufferSize" value="131072"/>
            <property name="threadPoolSize" value="4"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="cacheConfiguration">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">

                <property name="name" value="CACHENAME" />
                <property name="cacheMode" value="REPLICATED" />
                <property name="sqlSchema" value="XYZ" />
                <property name="indexedTypes">
                    <list> 
                        <value>com.entitlement.service.ignite.pojo.KeyPOJO</value>
                        <value>com.entitlement.service.ignite.pojo.ValuePOJO</value>
                    </list>
                </property>
                <property name="readThrough" value="true" />
                <property name="writeThrough" value="true" />
                <property name="writeBehindEnabled" value="true" />
                <property name="WriteBehindFlushFrequency" value="1000"/> 
                <property name="cacheStoreFactory">
                    <bean
                        class="org.apache.ignite.cache.store.cassandra.CassandraCacheStoreFactory">
                        <property name="dataSourceBean" value="cassandraAdminDataSource" />
                        <property name="persistenceSettingsBean" value="myPersistanceBean" />
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
```

Comment: Can you add a little more information? What is your cluster configuration? How much data? How complex is your query -- is it a simple select, a complex join, somewhere between? Anything else happening on Ignite at the sometime? (Still loading data perhaps, compute jobs running?)

Comment: You still need to give more details. Right now the question looks like "I have a this basic configuration but something isn't working" and people need much more to help you. The best way would be to create a small reproducer (code + configurations + steps to run) and share that.

Comment: an interim update. we have changed the cacheMode as PARTITIONED instead of REPLICATED and found that the query performance is consistent. I guess the behaviour was due to REPLICATED with only one node up. I will add this to the answer part once we are able to finalise this understanding with more testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we have changed the cacheMode as PARTITIONED instead of REPLICATED and found that the query performance is consistent. I guess the behavior was due to REPLICATED with only one node up.